# Using xpath,how to fetch particular xml node value when node contains multiple value?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is the xml from which i want to retrieve the value.

```
<dsml>
<entries>
<entry dn="uid=7686,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
<att name="uid">
<value>7568766</value>
<value>756876634</value>
</att><att name="callname">
<value>jhsadkjh</value>
<value>jhsadkjhakjdgakj</value>
</att></entry>
</entries>
</dsml>
```

As you can see that each attribute is having 2 values associated with it. I want to fetch only first one.
Below are some xpaths i have used:

```
//dsml/entries/entry/att[@name = 'uid']/value[1]
//dsml/entries/entry/att[@name = 'uid']/value/[1]
```

But its always throwing exception.

Comment: _But its always throwing exception._ - Adding the exception to your question would be a big help.

Comment: @Loic M.   Do change user-provided code or markup unless you are certain you're properly representing OP's intent without affecting the issue at hand; in this case you cannot be and should not have made such changes.   Rolled back.

Comment: @DanielHaley..The exception thrown is exceptionjavax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath fetch only second 'value' tag from each tag named 'att':

```
//dsml/entries/entry/att/value[1]
```

or, if you want to fetch 'value' only from "uid", you can use:

```
//dsml/entries/entry/att[@name='uid']/value[1]
```

Comment: For *//dsml/entries/entry/att[@name='uid']/value[1]*, I am getting "NullException"

Comment: I have tested here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
It works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

`att` and `attr` aren't the same element. Also, `</enteries>` can't close `<entries>`.

The following worked for me in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
/dsml/entries/entry/att[@name = 'uid']/value[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using different names for the same element. `entries` as open tag and `enteries` as closing tag. These names should be identical. Also in xml the name of element is `att` and in Xpath you are trying to find `attr`